# Order that variables appear in plot output of proc freq

Tags: sas

I have created a frequency plot using the plot option in proc freq. However, I am not able to order that I want. I have categories of '5 to 10 weeks' 'Greater than 25 weeks', '10 to 15 weeks', '15 to 20 weeks'. I want them to go in the logical order of increasing weeks but I'm not sure how to do that. I tried using the order option but nothing seemed to fix that.

A possible solution would be to code the order I want as values of 1-5, order them using the order= option and then have a label for 1-5. But I'm not sure if that's possible.

Tried the order= option, however, that didn't fix the issue.

I want the bins to show up as 'less then 5 weeks' '5 to 10 weeks' '10 to 15 weeks' '15 to 20 weeks' '20 to 25 weeks' 'greater then 25 weeks'

Comment: please share the code and sample data

Comment: Is your variable numeric with values 1 to 5 and you are using a format ?  Or is your variable character with the actual labels as the value?

Answer (score 0):

When the `Proc FREQ` plot displays the tabled variables values in alphabetic order, and the plot option `order=` is not specified you have the following scenario

- variable is character
- display order is default (`INTERNAL`)

Note: Other frequency plotting techniques, such a `SGPLOT` `VBAR` recognize midpoint axis specification that can control the explicit order the character values appear.  `Proc FREQ` does not have a plot option for mxaxis.

You are correct in presuming an inverse map (or remap, or unmap) from label to a desired ordered value is essential.  The are two main ways to *remap*

- custom format to map label to a character value (via `PUT`)
- custom informat to map label to a numeric value (via `INPUT`)

Once you have remapped the labels to a value, you need a second custom format to map the values back to the original labels.

Example:

```
* format to map unmapped labels back to original labels;
proc format;
  value category
  1 = 'Less than 5 weeks'
  2 = '5 to 10 weeks'
  3 = '10 to 15 weeks'
  4 = '15 to 20 weeks'
  5 = '20 to 25 weeks'
  6 = 'Greater than 25 weeks'
  ;

  * informat to unmap labels to numeric with desired freq plot order;
  invalue category_to_num
  'Less than 5 weeks'     = 1
  '5 to 10 weeks'         = 2
  '10 to 15 weeks'        = 3
  '15 to 20 weeks'        = 4
  '20 to 25 weeks'        = 5
  'Greater than 25 weeks' = 6
  ;

* generate sample data;    
data have;
  do itemid = 1 to 500;
    cat_num = rantbl(123,0.05,0.35,0.25,0.15,0.07);  * for demonstration purposes;
    cat_char = put(cat_num, category.);              * your actual category values;
    output;
  end;
run;

* demonstration: numeric category (unformatted) goes ascending internal order;
proc freq data=have;
  table cat_num / plots=freqplot(scale=percent) ;
run;

* demonstration: numeric category (formatted) in desired order with desired category text;
proc freq data=have;
  table cat_num / plots=freqplot(scale=percent) ;
  format cat_num category.;
run;

* your original plot showing character values being ordered alphabetically
* (as is expected from default order=internal);
proc freq data=have;
  table cat_char / plots=freqplot(scale=percent) ;
run;

* unmap the category texts to numeric values that are ordered as desired;
data have_remap;
  set have;
  cat_numX = input(cat_char, category_to_num.);
run;

* table the numeric values computed during unmap, using format to display
* the desired category texts;
proc freq data=have_remap;
  table cat_numX / plots=freqplot(scale=percent) ;   * <-- cat_numX ;
  format cat_numX category.;                         * <-- format ;
run;
```